# Microprofile Implementation for standalone Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, microprofile

does anybody know if it is planned to implement Eclipse Microprofile in the standalone Wildfly server (not Thorntail)? As the features in the microprofile seem to be usable to any application server, I would appreciate this a lot!

There exist 2 wildfly extensions (https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-microprofile-config and https://github.com/jmesnil/wildfly-microprofile-health) and the microprofile-rest-client is packaged into Wildfly 12, but no full microprofile support exists.

Thanks!

Comment: There's work underway to extract the MicroProfile implementation code from WildFly Swarm into a set of modules that could be used by any vendor or implementation. Once that happens it would be possible for them to be used in WildFly, but entirely up to that team as to what they plan

Comment: @Ken Thank you! Could you tell a timeline when this is going to happen, or could I follow the progress somewhere?

Comment: there's a Google Group already for the new shared implementations: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shared-eclipse-microprofile-implementations

Announcements and details will be provided in that group

Answer (score 0):

MicroProfile 3 is fully included since WildFly 19.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, MicroProfile is in WFLY for some time - https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/main/microprofile. Also, since it is possible from MicroProfile 4.1 to certify, we have requested certification for WFLY 25 - https://github.com/microprofile/microprofile-wg/issues/100.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30136984)